# How can my bash scripts ensure resulting files have group read permissions?

Tags: bash, file-permissions

I have a set of users who are running scripts on an Ubuntu box that *ought* to allow them to overwrite some output.

Imagine the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=$1
echo "Hello, $NAME" > output.txt
```

When ONE user runs this, we get the following permissions on `output.txt`: `-rw-r--r--`.  However, when a different user runs it, we get `-rw-r--r--`.

My ensemble of scripts includes BASH, Python and Scala.  Is there anything I can set at the directory or user level to ensure that new files will get created  as `-rw-rw-r--` by default?

Comment: Why don't you just create the file ahead of time with the correct permissions. As long as nothing deletes the file, its permissions will stay intact.

Comment: Right.  I could do that, but I was seeking new knowledge and something that might simplify what I'm doing.  The provided answer helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `umask` command with `002` octal mask.

Run:

```
umask 002
```

at the start of your script to make script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

umask 002
NAME="$1"
echo "Hello, $NAME" > output.txt
```

`umask 002` will set default directory permissions to `775` and default file permissions to `664`.

The octal notations are as follows:

```
0 : read, write and execute
1 : read and write
2 : read and execute
3 : read only
4 : write and execute
5 : write only
6 : execute only
7 : no permissions
```